# Proguard for java obfuscation, migrate from windows to mac, cannot find classes.jar

Tags: java, macos, migration, proguard, rt.jar

I'm migrating a java project from Windows to macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra). I want to use ProGuard, triggered from an ant script. On Windows I added rt.jar as input to ProGuard. I've learned that the equivalent on macOS should be classes.jar, found at for example

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Classes/classes.jar.
```

On my system, in 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
there are folders 'Current' and 'A' and no classes.jar under any of them. 
I have JDK 10 at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk`. In `Contents/Home/lib` there are in all 793 items, including a number of .jar and `.dylib` files. Is any of those the equivalent of rt.jar or can I find it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to my question:
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/discussion/182455/thread/5ac4a153/?limit=25#28db

Runtime classes can now be added as modules to Proguard. They reside in 
[java-home]/Contents/Home/jmods

Running
jdeps myjar.jar

returns the library modules to add for running proguard on myjar.jar